# How to make call between two pjsip applications locally?

Tags: local, sip, pjsip

I'm new to SIP and I'm using [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) as my stack.

I've successfully built `pjsua` on Windows. I can make call to another `pjsua` instance, with the help of a SIP server.

Is there a way to run 2 pjsua instances locally, or in LAN, and **WITHOUT** any SIP server (registra, proxy, ...) and allow to make call between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you might have got answer, might help anyone who comes across this page.

yes, it is possible. Start 2 instances of pjsua on 2 different ports. Try *"--local-port"* option. Call from 1st to 2nd by implicitly specifying the port *"sip:178237@192.168.10.10:5090"*. Each instance will act as uas for incall and uac for outcall